# How to extract specific part of string in python using regular expresion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler

I want to extract specific part of a string using regular expression in python?
Like suppose the string is http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Okeoghene.html
and i want to want to extract Okeoghene out!
Like i m using following code

```
import re
x = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Okeoghene.html"
print(re.findall('^_(.+).$',x)
```

But i m not getting the desire output maybe i have formulate the regular expression wrongly :-( .I m kinda new at python so please help me out

Comment: Provide more examples for this? Do you want the last word from the html file separated by underscrore?

Comment: Maybe you need something like `”_([^_]+?)\.”` and `findall` will return all the matches, I guess you need to select the last?

Comment: What did you expect that the `^` would mean at the beginning of the regular expression?

Comment: Thanks for your help my problem is solved now

Answer (score 1):

Your regex pattern is slightly off.  Consider this version:

```
x = "http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/known_by_Okeoghene.html"
matches = re.findall('_([^_]+)\.[^._]+$', x)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['Okeoghene']
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
_         match the last underscore
([^_]+)   match the term you want, excluding underscores
\.[^._]+  then match an extension
$         until reaching the end of the input
```

Note that we ensure that the last underscore is really the last one by excluding that character from the rest of the pattern.

Comment: Dont got that buddy !